# How to print a sub field value from a repeater in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to print a value from a sub field. I have the reapeater "faixas" that has the sub fields: "nome", "interprete" and "letra". On the custom fields area, I have the field "upc" that I print easily using `echo('"'.get_field('upc').'";');`, but when I try to do the same with "nome, interprete and letra", they just don't print. I already tried to print using `echo('"'.get_sub_field('nome').'";');`, but it didn't worked. I don't know if I need to point the sub field for the faixas repeater, can please someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for it I've found this solution:

```
if(have_rows('faixas')):
                 while(have_rows('faixas')) : the_row();
                 $letra = get_sub_field('letra');
                 echo $letra;
                 $nome = get_sub_field('nome');
                 echo ' ; '.$PHP_EOL.$nome;
         endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I'm assuming you're using ACF to store that repeater.
If that is the case, this should do the trick:

```
$faixas = get_field('faixas');

foreach ($faixa in $faixas) {
    echo('"'.$faixa['nome'].'";');
    echo('"'.$faixa['interprete'].'";');
    echo('"'.$faixa['letra'].'";');
}
```

When getting a repeater, you receive an array of the rows inside it (which I store in `$faixas` in this example).
In turn, each row is an associative array where the keys are the subfields' names.

Hope this helps, keep on coding!

Comment: That didn't worked for me, but thanks for your time and attention anyway! I've posted the solution I've found, if maybe you're interested.